# How to resolve Festival tts command returning `lexicon english_poslex not defined` error?

Tags: linux-mint, festival, text-to-speech

I have installed festival tts.

Now when I try running

`echo "Helllloooo!  Is anyone home?" | festival --tts`

I get the output

`lexicon english_poslex not defined`

How do I resolve this error?

I'm running Linux Mint by the way.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button, you will see the standard reason for downvotes. There is no requirement to post any additional comments, though it's generally encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=677277 thanks to @Rinzwind

I ran the command

`sudo apt-get install festlex-poslex`

and that fixed the error.